# Display array elements along with indices in WinForms Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I want to display elements of array with the respective index alongside on the UI in Winforms Visual Studio.What is the best way to do it ? Please reply.

Comment: there is no best way until we know what your use case is. There may be tonnes of ways

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually I have an array. What I want is 2 rows * 256 columns kind of representation. In the top row or we can say first row index value should be displayed and the row below it their corresponding values. Please help.I know we can see it in watch window as well .But I need it to be there on User Interface

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple ways is to use a `DataGridView` component and set its `DataSource` property to a collection of index-value pairs generated from this array:

```
var arr = new[] { 11, 22, 33 };
dataGridView1.DataSource = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length)
    .Select(i => new { index = i, value = arr[i]})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Do we have any tutorial so that I can follow . I am sorry but I am a beginner .Please help

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't recommend any specific one but simple google search reveals plenty of them: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx, https://www.thoughtco.com/programming-winforms-in-c-958381, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/tutorial-working-with-windows-forms-part-i/